# codeigniter model call not working from one of the controllers

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting a weird error when trying to call a model method from one of my controllers say problem.php, all the values are fine but `$this->db->get();` returns false, even the query returned from `$this->db->last_query()` is fine.
And the main issue is, when i pass the same values from another controller say test.php, everything works fine. Is this some caching issue?

Heres my code for the model

```
function how_many_left($product_id)
{
    var_dump($product_id);
    $sql="select * from invite where product_id=".$product_id." and accepted = 1";
    echo "<br/>Product id:".$product_id."<br/>";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    $invites = $query->num_rows();
    echo $invites;

    $this->db->select('quantity');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
    $query2 = $this->db->get_where('product_inventory');
    $quantity = 0;
    foreach ($query2->result() as $row) 
    {
        $quantity = $row->quantity;
    }
    $inventory = $quantity - $invites;
    return ($inventory);
}
```

the call from the controller which is not working

```
foreach ($user_list as $product_id => $value) {
            if (!isset($product_wise_invites[$product_id])) 
            {
                $product_wise_invites[$product_id] = array();
            }
            if($this->debug_mode())
            {
                echo "Product id to get error on :<br/>";
                var_dump($product_id);
            }
            $invites_left = $this->Product->how_many_left($product_id);
```

output of the controller not working

```
int(1349375633) 
select * from invite where product_id=1349375633 and accepted = 1
Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/application/models/internal.php on line 1135
```

the call from the working controller

```
   function invite_server_test()
    {
        $product_id=1349375633;
        $this->Product->how_many_left($product_id);
    }
```

The output of the working controller:

```
int(1349375633)
Product id:1349375633
select * from invite where product_id=1349375633 and accepted = 1
0
```

Comment: What is the error? You are not very clear in your question. What is the actual problem? Is the model function working? is your problem caused when calling the model method in your controller?

Comment: the function is not working from one of the 2 controllers, i get the error "Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/application/models/internal.php on line 1135 ", but when i call the function directly from another controller with the same parameters, i get no error, the first controller is a very long script and this method is called somewhere in the middle

Comment: update: theres one model call before the call with error, that inserts some records into the db, it was working fine, but if i comment it out, i get no error in these select statements

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a *non-object* `that means that $query isn't an object as you expected to be... from the controller method that is not working, how is `$product_id` defined? how do you assign it a value?

Comment: if you look at the output i've mentioned above, the $product_id is an integer with the value 1349375633, and when I echo $this->db->last_query() after $this->db->get(), i get select * from invite where product_id=1349375633 and accepted = 1, which is a perfectly fine query, but $this->db->get() is returning false meaning it could not execute the query hence $query is not an object as it should be

Comment: can you please provide me with the entire controller method? either update you question with it, or if its too long you can paste it [here](http://bpaste.net/+php) and just provide the link to it.